# Function which takes a integer n number and sets nth bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to write  a function which is something as below . i want to set a nth bit in the integer . for example i want to set 6th bit in number 8.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int set_bit(int number , int postion);

int main()
{
   int a;
   a=(8,6);
}

int set_bit(int number , int position)
{
   number = number |(1<<position);
}
```

the above function doesnt work. can anybody correct me?

Comment: You aren't even calling set_bit. You just do `a=(8,6);` try `a=set_bit(8,6);` and in `set_bit` you must return `number`.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. You're not calling the function: `a=(8,6)` should read `a = set_bit(8, 6)`.
2. You're not returning the value from the function: `number = number |(1<<position)` should read `return number | (1 << position)`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want want to return `number`, as **arguments are passed by value in C**. So simply modifying `number` inside the function has no effect for the caller.

As ruakh mentioned in the comments your syntax for calling the function isn't right.

Try:

```
int set_bit(int number , int position)
{
    return number | (1 << position);
}

/* ... */

a = set_bit(8, 6);
```

As a side note: **are you sure a single line of code warrants a separate function** ?

Comment: Actually, abstraction is worthy of creating separate method.  Just the fact that it make readability better is good, for example.

Comment: By the way, clear bit would be: return number &= ~(1 << position);

Answer (score -2):

Does the "`return number|(1<<position)`" work in all cases

If `position`th bit is already set and we tried to set the `position`th bit again will a overflow occur to `(position+1)`th bit...